# Reactjs - toggling class indipendently with right way

Tags: reactjs, tsx

I am trying to add a class and remove it it's available already. I am doing to for each element separately. but it always refers the last element. what is the correct way to do this?

is there any easy and elegant way to do this?

here is my component:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  divRef;
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.divRef = React.createRef();
  }
  toggleView = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(this.divRef.current.classList.contains("active")){
          this.divRef.current.classList.remove("active"); //always refer div 2!?
          return;
        }
        this.divRef.current.classList.add("active");
    }
  render(){
     return (
    <div class="parent">
      <div ref={this.divRef}>
      1
      <a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.toggleView(e)}>toggle</a>
      </div>
      <div ref={this.divRef}>2
      <a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.toggleView(e)}>toggle</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ba5wdj?file=src%2FApp.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would utilize `state` to achieve this. No need for `refs`.

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      view1: false,
      view2: false
    };
  }
  toggleView = (e, view) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ [view]: !this.state[view] });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="parent">
        <div className={this.state.view1 ? "active" : ""}>
          1
          <a href="#" onClick={e => this.toggleView(e, "view1")}>
            toggle
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className={this.state.view2 ? "active" : ""}>
          2
          <a href="#" onClick={e => this.toggleView(e, "view2")}>
            toggle
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tfhk1s?file=src%2FApp.js)

EDIT:
Here I show how this approach scales when we have lots of items

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

const NUM_ITEMS = 20;
const items = Array.from({ length: NUM_ITEMS }).map((_, idx) => ({
  title: "title" + idx,
  active: false
}));

const Item = ({ active, title, onToggle }) => (
  <div className={active ? "active" : ""}>
    {title}
    <a
      href="#"
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        onToggle();
      }}
    >
      toggle
    </a>
  </div>
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items
    };
  }
  toggleView = idx => {
    const items = [...this.state.items];
    items[idx] = { ...items[idx], active: !items[idx].active };
    this.setState({ items });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="parent">
        {this.state.items.map((item, idx) => (
          <Item
            key={item.title}
            active={item.active}
            title={item.title}
            onToggle={() => this.toggleView(idx)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tfhk1s?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: How to add with existing class? for me it's not working:  `<div className={`info + ${this.state.view1 ? 'active' : ''}`}>`

Comment: there is a tiny library that helps with this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do that by using two separate ref's ,here is the demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b1wa4f?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score -1):

I got with this:

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  divRef;
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.divRef = React.createRef();
  }
  toggleView = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const element = e.currentTarget.parentElement.classList;
        if(element.contains("active")){
          element.remove("active");
          return;
        }
        element.add("active");
    }
  render(){
     return (
    <div class="parent">
      <div ref={this.divRef}>
      1
      <a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.toggleView(e)}>toggle</a>
      </div>
      <div ref={this.divRef}>2
      <a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.toggleView(e)}>toggle</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

if any one finds, it's not a right way, let me know

Comment: please see my answer for a much simpler solution

Comment: the issue is, if i have 20 element, I need to add all 20 in state. it's look like much unclean, Is it or not?

Comment: actually no, as you are missing a fundamental part of React here - it being state driven. I'll update my answer to illustrate this

Comment: @thedude is absolutely right, his answer should be accepted.